# Facebook share can't get page og:title and og:description

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook

I am trying a facebook share button on my test site, but it can't get the og:title and og:description.

After I debug on: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

It shows `Object at URL 'http://okxok.asia/ItemDetail/Lifestyle-2' of type 'article' is invalid because the given value '' for property 'og:url' could not be parsed as type 'url'.`

I don't know what error is this, I check the og:url is okay.

Here is my screenshot for page details:

[image: SS]

Here is my screenshot for share pop-up:

[image: SS2]

Comment: Can you show us the html of this page by viewing the source, or just give us the url

Comment: hi @Bit68, my url is http://okxok.asia/ItemDetail/Lifestyle-2

Answer (score 0):

You are generating the meta tag with Javascript which Facebook will not parse. That tag must be sent out with the page and not generated by the clients. So Facebook will only ever see what you send directly to the client which is this:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="">
```